# PHP File Upload not Working with 2 input file types

Tags: php, file, upload

I am creating PHP file which has requirement of two file type inputs so i have written code for the same but the form is not being submitted. When I click submit button nothing happens.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="paper.php">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="file" class="col-sm-4 text-right control-label col-form-label">Select Cover Image</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="pfile" class="col-sm-4 text-right control-label col-form-label">Select Article PDF</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="pfile" name="pfile">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block"><?php echo ucfirst($op).' Article'; ?></button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

here is the PHP code I have written

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$targetDir = "uploads/paper/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath);

    $ptargetDir = "uploads/paper/pdf/";
    $pfileName = basename($_FILES["pfile"]["name"]);
    $ptargetFilePath = $ptargetDir . $pfileName;
    $pfileType = pathinfo($ptargetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pfile"]["tmp_name"], $ptargetFilePath);
}
```

what will be the issue?

Comment: what have you done to try debugging this so far?When you say "nothing happens" - please explain "nothing" ~ as the above looks OK

Comment: Can you please explain more what you mean by nothing happens when you submit the form? Because I copied your form and when I submit it, it does submit.

Comment: Try var_dump($_FILES); in php code.

Comment: The issue was due to NicEdit text editor. When I removed the references it worked properly.